# SetThreadpoolTimer, what does it do with an absolute time in the past?

Tags: winapi

`SetThreadpoolTimer` is used by my app to periodically ping a server to report my app is alive. My app records the time whenever it sends a ping and persists it to a file.

If my app is restarted it loads the last ping time. What happens if the app calls `SetThreadpoolTimer` with `lastPingTime + period`.

Potentially, this time is in the past!

Will `SetThreadpoolTimer` catch up and fire immediately for the missed event?

If I also specify a period to `SetThreadpoolTimer`, could the timer immediately fire multiple times to catch up on all the missed events?

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/threadpoolapiset/nf-threadpoolapiset-setthreadpooltimer) does not explain what happens when using absolute times that are in the past.

Comment: Perhaps a bit of experimentation is in order?

Comment: *Will SetThreadpoolTimer catch up and fire immediately for the missed event?*, must, despite this and undocumented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is MSDN sample for [Thread Pool Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/using-the-thread-pool-functions), and modify it like:

```
SYSTEMTIME sys = { 0 };
sys.wYear = 2020;
sys.wMonth = 7;
sys.wDay = 6;
sys.wHour = 8;
sys.wMinute = 0; //Suppose the current minute is 20, 0: the past time, 30: the future time.
sys.wSecond = 0;
sys.wMilliseconds = 0;
sys.wDayOfWeek = 1;

SystemTimeToFileTime(&sys,&ft);

SetThreadpoolTimer(timer,
    &ft,
    2000,
    0);

//
// Delay for the timer to be fired
//
Sleep(60000);
```

The missed event on 8:00 am has been fired immediately, but it only trigger once, then trigger every 2 seconds after it.

So, the short answer is:

> Will SetThreadpoolTimer catch up and fire immediately for the missed
> event?

Yes.

> If I also specify a period to SetThreadpoolTimer, could the timer
> immediately fire multiple times to catch up on all the missed events?

No, it only fire once and then follow the `msPeriod` to fire the event.